# Encounter a Java error "java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException" in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab

I am a newer here.

I got a java error very often when I use MATLAB. I am using an intel Mac, and the MATLAB version is R2012a.

The error is displayed in MATLAB Command Window like this:

```
java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:1971)
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:1945)
at apple.awt.CAccessibility$22.call(CAccessibility.java:370)
at apple.awt.CAccessibility$22.call(CAccessibility.java:368)
at apple.awt.CToolkit$CallableWrapper.run(CToolkit.java:1121)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
at apple.awt.CToolkit$CPeerEvent.dispatch(CToolkit.java:1211)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:672)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

As I know, this error happens only when I do some thing with mouse.

e.g.

> When I right-click a MATLAB function in Current Folder, then click open. I will get 80% chance to get this error. But If just type edit xxx.m in Command Window. then I will never get this error.
>
> When I drag a variable from Workspace to Variable Editor, I have a 80% chance to get this error. And I don't how to view a variable in Variable Editor by using command.

And, If this error happened, it will happen all the time until you turn off your MATLAB and reopen again if you do some thing with mouse. e.g. add a path to MATLAB search path by mouse, change directory by using mouse. If you reopen it, you will get a 80% chance again to get this problem when you using mouse.

Has anyone else seen these kind of problems? I know nothing about java, Can someone give me some suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any non-standard Mac add-ons or accessories? I was using Zoom2 which caused this problem to repeatedly manifest itself. In addition, are you using external monitors or an unusual display configuration?

Comment: Yes, I do use an external monitor for my Mac Book Pro by using a VGA adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to this specific error, but errors like this are quite common in Matlab. It is due to a bug in the Matlab GUI (which is written in Java). In this case, it looks like it tried to open the "Open file" dialog box, which is specific to the Mac, and failed, then it tried to get the position of that dialog box, which threw an error because it never correctly opened. Once Java throws an error, the GUI gets all confused and throws errors on everything you do.

You seem to know how to handle yourself, but here is general advice I give to labmates who get errors like this: those error messages look big an scary on your screen, especially when they keep popping up with every click after you trigger the first one, but don't panic, they are usually quite harmless. Calmly save your workspace from the GUI, which usually works, or with the command `save temp.mat`, which almost always works. Close Matlab once the workspace is saved, then reopen Matlab and load the workspace back, either from the GUI or with the command `load temp.mat`. Now your Matlab session is back and you haven't lost any data.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been reported earlier as well by people using `MATLAB version R2012a on MAC`

Try using other version.
Else file a bug report at TMW.